# UNIX read ()/write() function

Tags: c

I wrote one program .Its working fine till printing n variable after that its not printing buf2.Can anyone tell me why its happening and what should be the right approach?Same approach working fine for test.txt which is already created but not working for file.txt which we are creating in this code only

```
 #include<sys/stat.h>
 #include<sys/types.h>
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<fcntl.h>
 int main()
{
 int fd1,m,n;
 int fd2;
 fd2=open("test.txt",O_RDWR);
 fd1=open("file.txt",O_CREAT|O_RDWR,S_IRWXU);
    if (fd1==0)
      printf("error");
    else
     printf("file created \t %d\n",fd1);
 char buf[6];
 fgets(buf,6,stdin);
 printf("%s",buf);

 n=write(fd1,buf,6);
 printf("\n\n%d",n);
 char buf2[6];

 read (fd2, buf2,6) ;

 printf("final \t %s",buf2);
 //From here not getting desired o/p
 m=read(fd1,buf2,n);
 printf("\n\n%d",m);
 printf("\nstring is \n");

 write(1,buf2,m);

 close(fd1);
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: In `m=read(fd1,buf2,n);` you are trying to read from the end of the file you are writing.

Comment: ` if (fd1==0)  printf("error");` WRONG. open() returns -1 on error.

Answer (score 2):

After the First read file offset has moved to 7th byte of the file. To get back that to starting position use the `lseek` function.

```
off_t lseek(int fd, off_t offset, int whence);
```

in your case:

```
lseek(fd1, 0, SEEK_SET); // reposition fd1 to beginning of file
```

and checking the condition you have to compare the return value of `open` with `-1`.

```
if ( fd1 == -1 )
```